# How to declare user_id on ModelViewSet in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Foreignkey root is
User> Comparelist > obj

I don't know what's wrong with my code.
Error message said me comparelist required user_id

accounts> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

from .managers import UserManager
from core.models import TimestampedModel


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, TimestampedModel):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

accounts> serializers.py

```
from .models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            password = validated_data['password']
        )
        return user
```

ImageConverters> models.py

```
from django.db import models

from accounts.models import User


class CompareList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner")
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Obj(models.Model):
    comparelist = models.ForeignKey(CompareList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=500)
```

ImageConverters> serializers.py

```
from .models import CompareList, Obj
from rest_framework import serializers


class ObjSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Obj
        fields = ['object_name', 'image']


class CompareListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    objs = ObjSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CompareList
        fields = ['id', 'objs']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # print(dir(self))
        print(self)
        print('------------------')
        images_data = self.context['request'].FILES
        texts_data = self.context['request'].data
        comparelist = CompareList.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print(texts_data)
        for image_data, text_data in zip(images_data.getlist('image'), texts_data.getlist('object_name')):
            print(image_data, text_data)
            Obj.objects.create(comparelist=comparelist, image=image_data, object_name=text_data)
        return comparelist
```

ImageConverters> views.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from .models import CompareList, Obj
from .serializers import CompareListSerializer, ObjSerializer


class CompareListCreate(ModelViewSet):
   queryset = CompareList.objects.all()
   serializer_class = CompareListSerializer



class ObjListCreate(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Obj.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ObjSerializer
```

I sent post to server. But I got Error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi5hG.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a CompareList object without user field. Which violate with database relationship since user is required to create CompareList object.
If authenticated user is the owner of a CompareList object(Assuming only authorized user should be authorized to perform this action). update your serializer create method like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    # print(dir(self))
    print(self)
    print('------------------')
    images_data = self.context['request'].FILES
    texts_data = self.context['request'].data
    comparelist = CompareList.objects.create(**validated_data, user=self.context['request'].user)
    print(texts_data)
    for image_data, text_data in zip(images_data.getlist('image'), texts_data.getlist('object_name')):
        print(image_data, text_data)
        Obj.objects.create(comparelist=comparelist, image=image_data, object_name=text_data)
    return comparelist
```